# How to clone svn repo with git svn and be able to commit to both git and svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, porting, dcommit

I have the following scenario:

I am porting a big repo from which some catalogs I would like to separate into git repositories with independent/separate history, e.g.:

```
git svn clone  --trunk=https://svne1.XXX.XXX.com/XXXX/svnroot/trunk/ https://svne1.XXX.XXX.com/XXXX/svnroot/trunk/src/project1 --username myname --no-metadata -A ~/Documents/users.txt
```

This will create a git repository with extracted source code from `src/project1` under the trunk and with separate history and I will be able to push it anywhere I desire.

But I need (for some time) to be able to push to svn repo as well and taking into account that I have downloaded only the history of one directory from my project and not the trunk it is not so trivial to allow:

```
git svn rebase
git svn dcommit
```

How can I do this then? Having extracted multiple repos from svn to git and commit to both git and svn (having in mind that history in those smaller git repos are different (subset) of history in svn)

**EDIT**:

After launching running the clone operation and then `git svn rebase` I would get:

```
git svn rebase
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

Comment: Why is it not so trivial to allow? Technically there should be no issue I guess. You just do `git svn dcommit` from your git-svn copy.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to "git svn dcommit" from a cloned git-svn repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734256/is-there-a-way-to-git-svn-dcommit-from-a-cloned-git-svn-repository). That will allow git clones to be setup so they can dcommit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `--no-metadata` if plan staying in sync:

> svn.noMetadata, svn-remote..noMetadata
>
> ```
>        This gets rid of the git-svn-id: lines at the end of every commit.
>
>        This option can only be used for one-shot imports as git svn will
>        not be able to fetch again without metadata.
> ```

I don't think you also need to specify `--trunk` unless you want to use branches, and if so - would expect trunk to be below the main url, not above.

Comment: This will checkout all the repo data and files from whole repo not from the subdirectory specified, e.g. `https://svne1.XXX.XXX.com/XXXX/svnroot/trunk/src/project1`

Comment: @Patryk did you try `git svn clone  https://svne1.XXX.XXX.com/XXXX/svnroot/trunk/src/project1` ? I would expect it to fetch what you intend to.